# Can there be unitialized bits if I assign unsigned int to signed int

Tags: c++, valgrind, bit, unsigned, signed

I have an unsigned integer (say 32 bit), When I assign this to a signed integer, Can there be uninitialized bits left in signed integer after conversion.

```
unsigned int i = 10 
int j = i;
```

I got an error from valgrind saying uninitialized bytes observed at

```
int func(long,int,int);
```

I see an unsigned int being passed to this func in third argument. I am suspecting can this unsigned-signed conversion cause this valgrind error

Comment: Why are you asking? Since you tagged your question with [tag:valgrind] was there something that makes you doubt about that?

Comment: You mean if there could be `1`s before main value? No. It assigns value 10 to signed integer

Comment: I don't understand `uninitialized` part - bit cab be either 0 or 1, if it is not set, it must be cleared. There is no third option.

Comment: @Diodacus, You could say the same for `int i;`, but reading that is UB and the key is that the compiler can assume it's never read until a value is given.

Comment: I got a valgrind error of uninitialized bytes. I am suspecting a conversion from unsigned int to signed can cause this

Comment: @user1660982 Please provide a [mcve] that reproduces your problem as required here.

Comment: @user1660982 That's not possible.  You did something else wrong.

Comment: Either the value you passed was bad to begin with, or it's a false positive from valgrind. The conversion can't cause it.

Answer (score 3):

When you assign to a variable, you're assigning the *value* on the right hand side, not the *object representation* of the right hand side.  So there will never be uninitialized bits (or bytes) after a variable has been assigned to.

Also, because a byte is the minimum addressable unit, you can't assign values to only certain bits in a byte.  It's all or nothing.

It is possible to only assign to particular bytes of a variable if done via a `char *` or via `memcpy`.  For example:

```
unsigned char c[] = { 1, 2 };
int j;
memcpy(&j, c, sizeof(c));
```

Supposing an `int` is 4 bytes, then only the first 2 bytes of `j` are written to and the last 2 remain uninitialized.